# How to get a list of overridable methods in VSCode for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

The question sums it up pretty well. I've tried pressing Ctrl+Space in the class body, typing override and Ctrl+Space, typing the name of the method which I want to override that is in the base class...

I've managed to get the IntelliSense to work in general for C# in VSCode, but can't get this to work.

I know that for Java there exists an extension that lets you use shortcuts with UI to generate getters, setters... and to override methods, but can't find one for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I've found vscode-solution-explorer extension that I believe lets me do that. Or at least enables vscode to generate a list of overridable methods.